# Subversion hangs during large commit

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

If I'm just commit a few files everything works fine but if I try to commit an entire project it just hangs about half way through and stops sending any more data. Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was the post commit script causing issues. We have an email that goes out after every commit and it includes a DIFF output so after about 8 megabytes of data it finally just croaks. I just temporarily disabled the script while I committed the whole project and everything went fine. :)